# My custom .desktop file doesn't show in the applications menu

Tags: .desktop

I have created my own .desktop file by copying an existing one

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Arduino IDE
GenericName=Arduino IDE
Comment=Open-source electronics prototyping platform
Exec="/home/username/Programme/Arduino-IDE/arduino"
Icon=arduino-arduinoide
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Electronics;
MimeType=text/x-arduino;
Keywords=embedded electronics;electronics;avr;microcontroller;
StartupWMClass=processing-app-Base
```

and modifying it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application in terminal
Name=Matlab
GenericName=Matlab
Comment=Open-source electronics prototyping platform
Exec=/home/username/Programme/Matlab/bin/matlab
Icon=arduino-arduinoide
Terminal=true
Categories=Development;IDE;Electronics;
MimeType=text/x-arduino;
```

This has worked once, but for whatever reason the applications menu can no longer find it.

I am running Ubuntu 20.10 on a HP Envy x360 15-ee0755ng.

Comment: Copy the relevant desktop-files to `~/.local/share/applications/` and retry. Also note that at least previous versions of MATLAB are normally started by `matlab -desktop`

Comment: Copying the .desktop file to that location unfortunately doesn't change anything in the applications menu. The command itself works fine, but even if it didn't, it should not matter for whether it shows up in the applications menu.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and logging back in? This usually works for me (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on an HP 15-db00115dx).